# Debian installation on software RAID (lilo.conf configuration)

Tags: debian, raid, installation, mdadm, boot-loader

Debian installation program has created lilo.conf:

```
boot=/dev/md1
root=/dev/md1
raid-extra-boot=mbr-only
```

But when i configure lilo i usually put these lines

```
disk=/dev/md1
sectors=63
heads=255
cylinders=60801
boot=/dev/sda
root=/dev/md1
map=/boot/map
```

Where /dev/sda is first item of RAID1 (And also i change sda to sdb and run lilo again, to be able to boot from second item if first item will die)

QUESTION:
Which way is better? Does debian installation program write boot-loading data to both of disks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The debian way is better, because lilo will automatically write the boot record for all disks in the raid set, excluding the raid device itself (because of the `mbr-only` option).

I'd even venture a guess lilo will tell you which devices it writes the boot record onto when you run it (possibly using `-v`). Can't check that myself, as I'm using grub on all my machines for a few years now...